# NameError: name 'pvalue' is not defined

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In the documentation here (https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#additional-outputs) at 4.5.2 there is a `pvalue.TaggedOutput()` yielded.

The `pvalue` seems to be hard to import, I have the import lines copied from the apache documentation and I use the `--save_main_session` option as well as the `save_main_session=True` in the `def run()` as well as `pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session` before I start the pipeline. All imports work for all functions and all Classes work in all functions. But not `pvalue`. I have also tried all of these in every possible combination as well as leaving them out. `pvalue` is always unknown.

I take all my code from the cookbook here: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/cookbook/multiple_output_pardo.py

Nontheless, there is no pvalue.
`NameError: name 'pvalue' is not defined [while running 'generatedPtransform-1725']`

This error is only generated when I use the Dataflowrunner, not when I use the Directrunner.

**Example of my DoFn**

```
class Splitter(beam.DoFn):

    TAG1 = 'kleintje'
    TAG2 = 'grootje'

    def process(self, element):
        splittertid = element.get('id')

        if splittertid < 100:
            yield pvalue.TaggedOutput(self.TAG1, element)
        else:
            yield pvalue.TaggedOutput(self.TAG2, element)
```

**Example of my run()**

```
def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    sources = [
        json.loads('{"id":72234,"value":1'),
        json.loads('{"id":23,"value":2}')
        ]

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
           | beam.Create(sources)
           | beam.ParDo(Splitter()).with_outputs(Splitter.TAG1,Splitter.TAG2,main=Splitter.TAG1)
```

** my imports **

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import argparse
import logging
import re
import json
import datetime
from jsonschema import validate

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import pvalue
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools import parse_table_schema_from_json
```

Comment: the source has `from apache_beam import pvalue`, are you doing this as well?

Comment: yes, I've added my imports, maybe I did it wrong somehow

Comment: Have you tried using it like this. import apache beam -apache_beam.pvalue.TaggedOutput I am wondering of something changes pvalue somehow. Or you could use beam.pvalue.TaggedOutput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow the dependencies on the Dataflowrunner got messed up. By loading a wrong set of dependencies and then removing them again things suddenly started working.
Importing like `from apache_beam import pvalue` seems to be right after all.

Maybe the lesson learned here is that it may be possible to have corrupt dependencies and you can fix those by a forced reinstall triggered by an install and uninstall of older or wrong `apache_beam` packages.

Answer (score 3):

You should try importing **pvalue** within your class Splitter due the dependencies should be declared within the classes and functions when using Apache beam.

Your code should be like this

```
class Splitter(beam.DoFn):
    from apache_beam import pvalue
    TAG1 = 'kleintje'
    TAG2 = 'grootje'

    def process(self, element):
        splittertid = element.get('id')

        if splittertid < 100:
            yield pvalue.TaggedOutput(self.TAG1, element)
        else:
            yield pvalue.TaggedOutput(self.TAG2, element)
```

You are able to use `from apache_beam import pvalue` normally with Directrunner due the code is running locally; however, when using the Dataflowrunner, the code should follow a structure to handle correctly the [dependencies](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/).

Comment: No this should be fixed by using `--save_main_session`.

Comment: importing directly in the class didn't work for me. I had to import pvalue in the class method that was using it (apache_beam v2.38)