# How can I make sure that my beam pipeline will not have unpickling errors when ran on Dataflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-beam

I am working with beam Pipelines and developing on them has for the most part been a pleasure. Being able to run and test locally my pipelines is a big plus.

However, I get less comfortable when moving things into my test cloud environment.
I am using the `save_main_session` argument to bring some custom transforms, however unpickling sometimes gets messy.

Here are a few examples I ran into:

- [I need to import `beam.pvalue` inside of my `DoFn`s to yield tagged output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59138545/nameerror-name-pvalue-is-not-defined)
- [I cannot invoke `super` method when creating a class inheriting from `DoFn` or `PTransform`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-6158)

All of this is of course fine as it is still under development, however it gets frustrating having to wait for the pipeline to be deployed on cloud dataflow  and the data to start running before seeing the errors happening.

I am looking for a solution where the pipeline fails locally, *before* running `python -m myscript --runner DataflowRunner ...` and the pipeline being uploaded to Dataflow, only to see the unpickling errors piling up.

The unpickling does not fail locally because the unpickler can check the code in  presence, but ideally, I would be looking for an option to not have this behavior, i.e run `python -m myscript --runner DirectRunner --unpickle-like-dataflow` so that the pipeline fails locally.